# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Sentry"

Tags: flutter, cocoapods, sentry

[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Sentry":
In Podfile:
sentry_flutter (from `.symlinks/plugins/sentry_flutter/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
Sentry (~> 7.11.0)

```
None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `Sentry (~> 7.11.0)`.
```

I am just trying to install sentry_flutter plugin in my futter project. Currently i am testing in ios device. But it gives the above error.

The error message seems straight forward enough. But i cannot manage to include this plugin in my project.

Comment: Could you post your pubspec.yaml?

Answer (score 9):

you can run `pod repo update` to update your local cache bcause it may be outdated.
If it doesn't fix the issue for you, you can delete your `Podfile.look` file on `ios` folder and run `pod install`